# Lexicographical Order - How does one handle comparison between capital letters

Tags: c, lexicographic

my lab is doing a "competition" where we write unit tests and try to push for robustness based on preconditions and post-conditions of code. I was wondering if Lexicographical Order deals with Capital Letters different from lowercase letters as I thought this would be a nice way to trip people up if there is a difference?

Comment: If C is concerned and its `strcmp` and friends, then the uppercase letters have lower values than lowercase and thus `fOo` will come before `foo`.

Comment: Depends on the definition used in the specific context. Some definition may be "ASCII order", meaning A<a; some may be "A==a" and then there are language issues such as Spanish "l<ll" or German umlauts etc.

Comment: Generally speaking, Lexicographical order is case-independent, so you can use `stricmp` and related functions. But, when you then get equality like, say, "cat" and "Cat" then publishing/lexicographic convention would place the uppercase before the lowercase. (Check a dictionary.) But the issue with non-ASCII stuffs like French accents, German umlauts, et cetera, is trickier to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, for example, the `min()` function on a string with a mix of upper and lowercase letters will return the first capital letter in said string as that is considered lexographically to be the smallest element:

```
min("abcDEF") # returns 'D'
```

This question may be useful to anyone arriving here from languages other than C.

In Python, strings are compared lexicographically based on their Unicode code points. This means that each character in the string is assigned a numerical value based on its position in the Unicode character set, and the characters are compared based on these values. In the Unicode character set, uppercase letters come before lowercase letters, so 'D' (which has a code point value of 68) comes before 'a' (which has a code point value of 97).

Therefore, when you use the min() function on the string 'abcDEF', it returns the character with the smallest code point value, which is 'D'.